# How to perform a complex query using AS alias

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, I am new here and just learning sql, so bear with me.

I have a simple question. Let's say I have a table called `voting` with the following columns:

```
id, token(int), candidate(int), rank(int)
```

.. and I want to perform a query like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM  voting 
  WHERE rank > t1.rank 
  AND   token = t1.token
```

.. where `t1` is

```
SELECT  rank,token 
  FROM  voting 
  WHERE candidate = $mycandidate
```

How can I do this in a single statement using AS alias, or whatever is the simplest method?

Please note that final table created may have rows with different candidates than i have specified i.e the rank,token variables are initially chosen according to candidate but once chosen they may contain any candidate value with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do, I believe:

```
 select
    v1.*
 from
    voting v1 inner join
    voting v2
        on v1.token = v2.token and
           v2.candidate = $mycandidate and
           v1.rank > v2.rank
```

*EDIT* changed `SELECT *` to `SELECT v1.*`

Comment: Actually the token column contains duplicate data with different candidate variables.So,your wanna method did't work here since i wanna fetch rows with other candidates too

Comment: After the last edit,it is working now.It is actually much simpler than i thought.Thanks..........................